# Object is undefined - dog2

Tags: java

When I try to set my Dog object to dog2 and then have it print out the information I obtained for dog1, it keeps saying one of my variables is undefined.  Below is my code for each component class as well as for main.  If I take out dog2 and just call print for dog1, everything works as it should.  I do not know what to do.  I have been working on this for the past two days with no headway.

```
public class Owner {

    private String ownerName;
    private int ownerSSN;
    private int ownerPhone;

    public String getOwnerName () {
        return ownerName;
    }

    public int getOwnerSSN () {
        return ownerSSN;
    }

    public int getOwnerPhone () {
        return ownerPhone;
    }

    public void setOwnerName (String own) {
        this.ownerName = own;
    }

    public void setOwnerSSN (int ssn) {
        this.ownerSSN = ssn;
    }

    public void setOwnerPhone (int phone) {
        this.ownerPhone = phone;
    }

    // created the default constructor and the overloaded constructor
    public Owner () {
        ownerName = "John Doe";
        ownerSSN = 0;
        ownerPhone = 0;
    }

    public Owner (String own, int ssn, int phone) {
        this.ownerName = own;
        this.ownerSSN = ssn;
        this.ownerPhone = phone;
    }
}

public class DOB {

    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;

    public int getDay () {
        return day;
    }

    public int getMonth () {
        return month;
    }

    public int getYear () {
        return year;
    }

    public void setDay (int day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public void setMonth (int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public void setYear (int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    // created the default constructor and the overloaded constructor for the DOB class
    public DOB () {
        day = 00;
        month = 00;
        year = 0000;
    }

    public DOB (int day, int month, int year) {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }   
}

public class DogLicense {

    private int licenseNum;
    private int licenseYear;
    private String licenseAuthority;

    public int getLicenseNum () {
        return licenseNum;
    }

    public int getLicenseYear () {
        return licenseYear;
    }

    public String getLicenseAuthority () {
        return licenseAuthority;
    }

    public void createLicenseNum (int license) {
        licenseNum = (license * 705);
    }

    // created the default contructor and the overloaded constructor for the DogLicense class
    public DogLicense () {
        licenseNum = 0;
        licenseYear = 0000;
        licenseAuthority = "PA";
    }

    public DogLicense (int lNum, int lYear, String authority) {
        this.licenseNum = lNum;
        this.licenseYear = lYear;
        this.licenseAuthority = authority;
    }
}

public class Dog {

    private String name;
    private DogLicense licenseNum;
    private Owner own;
    private DOB dob;

    // created the getters for the Dog Class
    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }

    public DogLicense getLicenseNum () {
        return licenseNum;
    }

    public Owner getOwn () {
        return own;
    }

    public DOB getDOB () {
        return dob;
    }

    // created the setters for the Dog class
    public void setName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setLicenseNum (DogLicense licenseNum) {
        this.licenseNum = licenseNum;
    }

    public void setOwner (Owner own) {
        this.own = own;
    }

    public void setDOB (DOB dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }


    // created the default constructor and the overloaded constructor with references to other classes
    public Dog () {
        name = "New Puppy";
        licenseNum = null;
        own = null;
        dob = null;     
    }

    public Dog (String name, DogLicense licenseNum, Owner own, DOB dob) {
        this.name = name;
        this.licenseNum = licenseNum;
        this.own = own;
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public void printDogInfo () {
        System.out.println(this.own.getOwnerName() + ", here is the following information pertaining to your dog.");
        System.out.println("Your dog's name is: " + this.name);
        System.out.println(this.name + "'s licensing number is: " + this.licenseNum.getLicenseNum());
        System.out.printf(this.name + "'s date of birth is: " + this.dob.getMonth () + "/" + this.dob.getDay () + "/" + this.dob.getYear ());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your phone number is: " + this.own.getOwnerPhone ());
        System.out.println("Your social security number is: " + this.own.getOwnerSSN ());
    }
}

import java.util.*;

public class TestDog {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner animal = new Scanner (System.in);

        Dog dog1 = new Dog ();

        System.out.print("Please enter the name of your dog here: ");
            String name = animal.next ();

        dog1.setName (name);
        System.out.println();

        // created the information pertaining to the Owner
        System.out.print("Please enter the name of the owner: ");
            String own = animal.next ();
        System.out.print("Please enter your 9 digit Social Security Number.  Do not include dashes. ");
            int ssn = animal.nextInt ();
        System.out.print("Please enter your phone number.  Please, do not include the area code or any dashes. ");
            int phone = animal.nextInt ();

        Owner owner1 = new Owner (own, ssn, phone);
        dog1.setOwner (owner1);
        System.out.println();

        // created the information for Date of Birth
        System.out.print("Please enter the day your dog was born (dd mm yyyy): ");
            int day = animal.nextInt ();
            int month = animal.nextInt ();
            int year = animal.nextInt ();

        DOB dob = new DOB (day, month, year);
        dog1.setDOB (dob);
        System.out.println();

        // created information for Dog License
        System.out.print("Please enter a one to four digit identifier number for your dog: ");
            int license = animal.nextInt ();
        System.out.print("Please enter the year you are obtaining your license number in: ");
            int lYear = animal.nextInt ();
        System.out.print("PLease enter the licensing authority in which you are registering your dog: ");
            String authority = animal.next ();
        System.out.println();

        DogLicense dog1License = new DogLicense (license, lYear, authority);
        dog1.setLicenseNum (dog1License);
        dog1License.createLicenseNum(license);


        dog1.printDogInfo ();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        Dog dog2 = new Dog (name, license, own, dob);
        dog2.printDogInfo ();

    }
}
```

Comment: Probably because `own` is **not** `owner1`. Also `license` is an `int`, while `dog1License` is a `DogLicense`. You should pick more meaningful variable names.

Comment: Elliott, that is not where my issue is.  I am having an issue with DOB portion when I call print for dog2.  I am not having any issues with the owner information

Comment: @Bec according to the code, that is your issue. The dob part is fine, the third parameter of the constuctor call is wrong.

Comment: The code you show will not compile because there is no Dog constructor that takes (String, int, String, DOB ) as its parameters.